# Which port actually Hubot points if the 8080 is pre-occupied?

Tags: hubot

I am using the `localhost:8080` for jenkins... and not sure how to get the host url for hubot, like where it runs

and how to change to change the port ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting from `node_modules > hubot > src > robot.coffee` did help

[image: port]